# React - Form with dynamic, controlled elements

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a large form with a lot of different input fields using MaterialUI- TextFields that need to be in certain order. I've made an array of objects that represent these fields and iterate through them based on their type in order to not repeat 20 times some components. After that I make a new array that combines all the components. A reduced example:

```
  const values = [
  {
    inputType: "text",
    label: "Name",
    name: "name"
  },
  {
    inputType: "date",
    label: "Date",
    name: "date"
  }
];

const Index = () => {
  const finalElements = [];
  const initState = {
    name: "",
    date: null
  };
  const [dataState, setDataState] = useState({
    ...initState
  });
  const handleFieldChange = (name, value) => {
    setDataState(() => ({
      ...dataState,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };
  const CustInput = props => {
    const { id } = props;
    return (
      <TextField
        label={id.label}
        name={id.name}
        value={dataState[id.name]}
        onChange={event =>
          handleFieldChange(event.target.name, event.target.value)
        }
      />
    );
  };
  const CustDate = props => {
    const { id } = props;
    return (
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          label={id.label}
          name={id.name}
          value={dataState[id.name]}
          onChange={date => handleFieldChange(id.name, date)}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
  };
  Object.entries(values).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    switch (value.inputType) {
      case "text":
        finalElements.push(<CustInput key={value.name} id={value} />);
        break;
      case "date":
        finalElements.push(<CustDate key={value.name} id={value} />);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
  const content = <>{finalElements}</>;
  return <Wrapper content={content} />;
};
export default Index;
```

My problem is that it seems like I don't control the state correctly because after inputing one character in some field the entire form re-renders and the text field becomes unfocused (I need to click again on the field in order to input another character). Can you help me figure what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: could you indent your code consistently please? It's pretty hard to see what's really going on.

Comment: Sorry. Still learning my way around. Hope that now it's ok to read.

Comment: possible typo: `setFormState` or `setDataState`?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is that you are defining CustInput and CustDate inside of the Index component. Try moving those component definitions outside of the Index component.

Comment: How would I go about using the state(value={dataState[...]}) for the values in the components though?

Comment: You would pass them down as props.

Comment: Hi. I moved the component definitions and passed down the needed props. Seems to be working fine until it gets to setting the value mentioned above. Can you give me an example how to properly update the state there using the state hook?